# meaning of the phrase "cutting wit"?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> Rail means "to revile or scold in harsh, insolent, or abusive language," whereas raillery usually suggests **cutting wit** that pokes fun good-naturedly.

I feel that *cutting* means *acute* there, but I am in doubt because neither the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cutting) nor [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cutting) dictionary give similar definitions.

Comment: It's really just a metaphorical use.  The wit is *sharp* or *piercing* or *incisive*, like a knife.  Merriam-Webster's adjective definition #3 is probably the closest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a New Yorker cartoon, drawn by Emily Flake, that describes cutting wit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Cutting wit** is humor  with a victim.